# Nature of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How to find either if this series is convergent or divergent?
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$

I tried divide it into $4$ series taking:
$i^n \in \{-1,1,i,-i\}$
But I reach nothing, any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your approach, write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{\sqrt[3]n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{2n}}-i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{2n-1}}$$ both of which are convergent series by the  [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) .